# Insinkerator and light switch

Tags: electrical, walls, switch

My insinkerator and a light bulb comes in to a wall socket. I replaced the switch panel. 
There were three wires total. 2 red, 1 black

Initially the light and insinkerator were independent with two different switches turning them on. However, with the new replaced switch when I turn on the light, Only THEN insinkerator turns on. The light turns on independently. However, the insinkerator needs the light to be on to be turned on

How can i make them independent again? I got the Di pole switch. Pics attached.

[image: See images here]
[image: See images here]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the inside of the wall socket, clearly showing the wires? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: what lightbulb are you talking about? ... what do you mean by `wall socket`? ... how could the light and the insinkerator be separate if there is only one switch?

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the back of the box please?

Comment: Perhaps you have you line in and out wired backwards? One switch is for the light, the other for your disposal, correct? Your line-in maybe wired incorrectly on the switch.

Comment: Thanks. What does that mean? Do I swap the red wires? How do I properly wire a line-in?

Comment: Just updated with picture of the box

Comment: Can you unfasten and pull out (but _NOT_ unwire), the receptacle and give us another photo of the box innards please?

Comment: Added Images above @ThreePhaseEel